# Authorization type Bearer Token on Postman

Tags: authorization, postman, bearer-token, express-jwt

I'm trying test a few endpoints using Postman.

All endpoint, require a token which can be obtain by log-in.

So I did this :

Request #1

[image]

After login success, I have access to the token from the response, then I store that token in my global variable.

```
let token = pm.response.json().location
console.log('Token : ', token.split("?token=")[1]);
pm.globals.set("token", token)
```

I need to use that token as Authorization type Bearer Token for my request #2.

[image: enter pastedescription here]

I can copy & paste that in the token box, but I tried to avoid doing that manually, is there a way to do it automatically so I can run these 2 requests in sequence?

Comment: You're setting the token as a global variable right? Can you not just use `Bearer {{token}}` in an Auth header on the second request? That Token input is only creating the same header.

Comment: ohh smart, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first, create an environment ( top right corner of postman - image below ) This
   is not a mandatory step by I suggest you to do for better handling of variables

[image]

I have modified the script to suit your need

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("ID", jsonData.Location.split("?token=")[1]);
```

Now this will export the value of the token ( screenshot below )

[image]

All you have to do next is to call the variable in request #2

[image]

**By this you don't have to manually copy, paste into request #2 every single time**

Comment: So basically my comment ;) You dont need to create an environment file as it's already getting set as a global variable. I would also suggest moving away from the old style syntax and use the `pm. *` api.

Comment: I'm still on the chrome extension so the "postman" syntax, also the reason for the environment is because in my postman I have 2 API's that generates token and i have to use the same variable ( project demand ) so I map it against different environments

Comment: I would migrate to the stand alone version of Postman, the chrome extension is not even actively worked on anymore. It's a major version behind the native application now.

Answer (score 0):

NO there isn't any till now. It has to be done manually if you want to have complete value or else you can store it in a variable and use that variable directly for the token.